# Fire extinguishers inside the coaches of long distance trains

Tags: trains, safety

Are fire extinguishers installed inside the coaches of express trains?

If not, why not?

Will the passengers be unable to use the fire extinguisher in case a fire takes place?
Or can the fire extinguisher itself trigger a fire in an express train?

Example:

Train travel from Washington D.C. to San Francisco.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what aspect of train fire safety you are concerned about here, but here is an article (UK-based) which describes some of the history and current developments in train fire safety: https://www.railengineer.co.uk/fire-safety-on-trains/

Comment: This question is too broad unless you are limiting it to a specific train company and route (let alone country).  AFAIK there is no train from DC to San Francisco (you'd have to take 2 or more different train routes), so that seems to be a random example rather than a real world one

Comment: Do you mean manual hand held fire extinguishers or automated fire suppression systems? Do you mean inside the coaches where passengers sit or in the mechanical/machinery areas? What's so special about the train route (express vs regular) that you think would affect the fire extinguishing capabilities?

Answer (score 2):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

> Are fire extinguishers installed inside the coaches of express trains?

Yes.  [Federal regulations require at least one fire extinguisher in each car.](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/49/239.101)

> If not, why not?

Not applicable (see above).

> Will the passengers be unable to use the fire extinguisher in case a fire takes place?

It's possible.  The passengers may be incapable of operating a fire extinguisher for some reason, or they may operate it incorrectly, or the fire extinguisher may be faulty.

> Or can the fire extinguisher itself trigger a fire in an express train?

Fire extinguishers generally are not capable of causing fires.

Comment: Thanks. That means there should be some personnel appointed by the Long distance express train service providers who have been trained in using Fire extinguishers. Passengers travelling in the train may or may not be able to use the fire extinguisher. There are emergency exits, fire alarms, smoke detectors and switches/chains to halt the train but in a running fast express train the fire will quickly move in the coaches. Fire fighters have to quickly come into action. I feel prevention is always  better than cure similar to a vaccine but still in case fire event occurs in a express train?